# How do you use google maps api with mocha testing since there is no html to add the script tag which google maps api requires

Tags: javascript, google-maps, testing, reactjs, mocha.js

I am trying to test my react application using mocha. I am using google maps api in my application. When I run my mocha tests, I get an error "ReferenceError: google is not defined". In my application I can use the API since I include the following script tag in my html.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&libraries=geometry,places,drawing&key=KEY></script>.
```

Mocha runs on node.js and there is no html to it. How do I use google maps with my mocha testing?

Example usage:

```
const bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
```

Comment: have you found a solution to this?

Comment: Yes I did. You can run mocha on the browser. You can find how you can  [here](https://mochajs.org/).  And once you do that, you can just include google maps in the script tag of the html running your mocha tests. Let me know if you still face troubles.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to this. 
You can run mocha tests on the browser. You can find instructions as to how [here](https://mochajs.org/#running-mocha-in-the-browser). Once you do this, you can just include the google maps in the script tag of the html running your mocha tests. The only downside to this approach is that you would now be running tests on a browser and not from command line. I needed to run the test on command line. I ran my mocha tests on the headless browser provided by phantomjs.

(Updated: included the correct URL to the instructions to run mocha on the browser)

Comment: This is the correct url: https://mochajs.org/#running-mocha-in-the-browser